# How is accuracy calculated in Battlefield 3?

Tags: battlefield-3

Since there is no official source for this kind of information and I haven't found any data on the internet, I'm asking this here. The details:

- In which cases shots are affecting the specific gun's/general accuracy? Will my accuracy go down, if I just stand at one place and put 1000 rounds in the ground?
- How is calculated rocket launcher's accuracy? Is the indirect damage a miss or a hit?
- What math is used? Shots hit / shots fired? Or something more complicated?
- *Off-topic*: Why is my general accuracy around 13, if 26 guns out of 30 in my top weapons have 18+ accuracy (sniper rifles 30+, pistols 20+, rocket launchers 55+).

Any info will do - personal observations, tests, videos, maybe game-file tear-downs or unpopular developer blog entries, or closed forum posts, *any*.

Comment: I can't give an authoritative answer, but I believe it's a factor of the number of shots fired divided by the number of shots that cause an effect on a target.  So yes, firing 1000 times into the ground will lower your accuracy.  Splash damage *should* count though.  Your accuracy may be low because you fire comparatively few rounds with the weapons you have high accuracy with.

Comment: @agent86 Well, I and several my buds were in doubt about firing in the ground, because one of them had a 42% accuracy by playing a lot on Metro and shooting people with a shotgun, and a couple of them had reported him, so he decided to spend some time shooting rounds into nowhere. He took the SAW and was shooting for like half an hour, almost non-stop. The accuracy never went down. About my top weapons - half of all kills are made by top three of them, and they are MP443 with 25%, SV98 with 35% and M98B with 31%.

Comment: All we've got is anecdotal evidence, so I'm not going to debate this further with you :)  Sorry if my experiences aren't matching up with yours.

Comment: @agent86 I agree, but it's at least something :)

Comment: My accuracy with the DAO-12 is >100%. This is because it is possible to hit multiple targets with one shot...

Answer (score 4):

It is simply `hits/shots fired`.

A hit is considered as anything that does damage to an opposing enemy/vehicle. Verifying my L96 accuracy, I have 1463 hits, with 4,119 shots fired. The site says my accuracy is 35.52% and doing the simple math, that's what that ratio is.

Edit: Answering your bullet points

1. Yes, your accuracy would go down if no damage is done to an enemy player.
2. Rocket accuracy is the same as all other weapons. Damage done = hit. It is how you can have over 100% accuracy with weapons since 1 shot could hit multiple players.
3. I answered originally
4. Your general accuracy is the total sum of your hits/shots fired for all your weapons. So while your top weapons have high accuracy ratings and make your general accuracy higher, your bottom weapons drop your general accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

It would have to be shots fired vs. shots hit. On the Battlefeed site, you can see that they show for each weapon.

[image]