# In determining accuracy statistics, is each round of on-target suppressive fire considered a missed shot?

Tags: battlefield-3

I've been considering putting some time into the Support class, but while looking through my stats thus far, a question immediately came to mind... I can't seem to figure out how accuracy statistics are affected by accurate suppressive fire. I've struggled to find a definitive answer to this, and my (admittedly weak) math skills and memory problems have led to nothing but frustration in my attempts at in-game experimentation.

I know that the contributing factors behind many BF3 statistics are still somewhat unclear, but this one seems like maybe it would be something that Support-focused players might be able to answer, just due to laying down so many LMG rounds. It also struck me as something that the devs might have taken into consideration, especially since the Support kit has suppressive fire listed as one of its primary responsibilities, if I remember correctly. 
Related questions that have been answered here as well as forum discussions (both those relating to suppressive fire itself, and those relating to the accuracy stat), while quite helpful in determining how suppression works in-game, don't seem to shed any light on how the former actually affects the latter.

Related Q & As:
[How is accuracy calculated in Battlefield 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45200/how-is-accuracy-calculated)

[Who and what can lay down suppressive fire?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32139/who-and-what-can-lay-down-suppressive-fire)

So, to be clear, when firing rounds of suppressive fire, do shots that properly inflict the motion blur effect on enemy targets still count against your accuracy percentage the same as missed shots?

Comment: "have led to nothing but frustration in my attempts at in-game experimentation." can you update your Q describing what tests you've run?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at the http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Suppressive_Fire posted by Foxtrot, the wiki says as follows:

> To suppress a target, simply shoot at them. The projectiles do not have to hit the target, they only have to pass through or land in a certain radius around the target.

Since the text specifically talks about hitting the target, i take that to mean suppression fire is missed shots on target.

If you take that as how the game treats suppression fire, then all shots that do not hit the enemy/enemy vehicle would be considered a missed shot.

Answer (score 0):

This is a related Q & A: 
[How is accuracy calculated in Battlefield 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45200/how-is-accuracy-calculated)

Otherwise:

http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Suppressive_Fire

Provides [limited] information the suppressive fire.  My recommendation is not to worry about overall accuracy; especially if you are going for the suppression medal.

My overall assumption is that if your bullets pass within an overall radius of the enemy, it counts towards suppression, not misses.  Especially in a battlefield, its going to be a team effort of moving from object to object - hopefully with covering fire. ( which suppresses the enemy ).

If you are concerned about accuracy, just relate to a per weapon base.

Comment: I am familiar with both pages; both are helpful for understanding Suppression/Accuracy respectively. Also, [this Q&A](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32139/who-and-what-can-lay-down-suppressive-fire) is rather enlightening regarding _what counts_ as on-target SF. However, for this question, Im simply trying to determine the exact stat mechanic touched upon in your paragraph starting w/ "My assumption is"- Useful input but not as straight an answer as I was hoping to find. How sure are you that SF rounds (ones that give SF points & cause the effect), are actually **raising** accuracy?